# ReportViewer Remote Datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, reporting-services, reportviewer

Good day,
I just uploaded a web application to azure.

I was working with a local database, it did not have credentials (user, pass), with windows authentication.

Now I'm using a remote database, the reports (.RDLC) do not work, with the application I use to design the reports and update the datasource, but I guess I'm not saving the credentials, this is the connection string.

```
<ConnectionProperties>
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
    <ConnectString>Data Source=miservidor;Initial Catalog=DataBase</ConnectString>
</ConnectionProperties>
```

Any example connection string? Or that the datasource of my .RDLC reports is a remote database.

Comment: Multiple questions (1) Is your web application running in VM? (2) Where is your SSRS. Is that in the same VM?

Comment: @Prawin it's not vm

Comment: Here is the solution: `<ConnectionProperties> 
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider> 
        <ConnectString>Data Source=mvc.syncfusion.com;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User ID=ssrs1;Password=RDLReport1</ConnectString> 
      </ConnectionProperties> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<ConnectionProperties> 
    <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider> 
    <ConnectString>Data Source=mvc.syncfusion.com;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;User ID=ssrs1;Password=RDLReport1</ConnectString> 
</ConnectionProperties>
```